# Put two different texts in the same place of an HTML page

Tags: html, css

I would like to put a text written in French on an HTML page and his hidden translation in English at the same place. A click on a JavaScript button will show the English text instead of the French one, by changing the `Visibility` attribut of each markup containing the text.

Maybe it's not the best way to do this sort of thing but I have to do it like this.

I've tried the following HTML and CSS code :

```
.presentationField {
    vertical-align: text-top;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 500px;
    border: 2px dashed blue;
}

<div id="frenchField" class="presentationField">
            <h1>Les villes du Québec</h1>

            <form>
            Veuillez saisir le nom d'une ville au Québec<br>
                <input type="text" id="recherche">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="englishField" class="presentationField">
            <h1>Cities of Québec</h1>

            <form>
            Please type the name of a town located in the province of Québec<br>
                <input type="text" id="recherche">
            </form>
        </div>
```

But it doesn't work : the English text is below the French one and I can't figure out why.

Comment: can you post some of your javascript code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this, just flip the visibility:

```js
function change() {
  document.getElementById('frenchField').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('englishField').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.presentationField {
  vertical-align: text-top;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 500px;
  border: 2px dashed blue;
}
#englishField {display: none;}
button {margin: auto; width: 200px; display: block}
```

```html
<div id="frenchField" class="presentationField">
  <h1>Les villes du Québec</h1>

  <form>
    Veuillez saisir le nom d'une ville au Québec
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="recherche">
  </form>
</div>
<div id="englishField" class="presentationField">
  <h1>Cities of Québec</h1>
  <form>
    Please type the name of a town located in the province of Québec
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="recherche">
  </form>
</div>
<button onclick="change()"> FR -> EN </button>
```

You can also check which one is active first if you wish to be able to go back to French.

Answer (score 1):

If the text should be in the same exact location, use the CSS `position` property to overlap them. You may also have to make use of the `z-index` property depending on your desired result.

Example:

```css
p{ color:red; font-size:200%; }
#alt{ color:blue; position:relative; top:-70px; }
```

```html
<p>Regular Word</p>
<p id ="alt">French Word</p>
```

Or you could use `display:none` instead of `visibility:hidden` which removes the element from the layout rendering as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should not put the translation as Hidden behind any other element. You should grab it from somewhere and just set the innerHTMLValue value.

```
function Translate(Language)
{
    if(Language=='English')
    {
       document.getElementById("myBox").innerHTML = "Hi";
    }
    else
    {
       document.getElementById("myBox").innerHTML = "Hola";
    }

}
```

Then you can simply pass the language. You should construct the Language Library as a Javascript object since that would be really the best way based on object oriented design and future requests may come that requires this solution.